# Is there a way to create excel worksheets out of a powerpoint presentation?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I want to create excel worksheets out of a powerpoint presentations where i can keep the format of the powerpoint slides and am able to adjust certain values. Does anyone know a way?

I heard of creating powerpoint slides out of a excel worksheet, though I need to go the other way around as I want to keep the format of the powerpoint slides but need to be able to adjust certain values. Does anyone know a way?

I basically need a Excel worksheet that looks and works like my powerpoint slide.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
.
.
.
'Adds a slide to the presentation - is this also possible for worksheets?
 Set mySlide = myPresentation.slides.Add(myPresentation.slides.Count + 1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly   

' Pastes the copied range out of the excel into the Powerpoint
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2    
.
.
.
```

What I would like to do is to turn these around, I cant find any hints how to. Neither in books nor on the internet.

Comment: The answer to your question is *Yes*.  What have you tried thusfar?  SO can help with *specific* coding issues, but is not a code-for-you service.

Comment: I added what I worked with so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rudimentary approach. This code, which is run from within Excel, requires a reference to the powerpoint object library. It creates a new worksheet in Excel, one for each slide, and copies across the slide contents (ie. all the shapes). It positions the shapes per where they are located on the slide. A bit of a concept starter. Cheers.

```
Option Explicit

' ---> ADD REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT POWERPOINT OBJECT LIBRARY

Public Sub CreateSheetsFromSlides()

    Dim vPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim vPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim vSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim vPowerpointShape As PowerPoint.Shape

    Dim vExcelShape
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet

    ' Open the powerpoint presentation
    Set vPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set vPresentation = vPowerPoint.Presentations.Open("source.pptx")

    ' Loop through each powerpoint slide
    For Each vSlide In vPresentation.Slides

        ' Create a new worksheet ... one per slide ... and name the worksheet same as the slide
        Set vSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        vSheet.Name = vSlide.Name
        MsgBox vSheet.Name

        ' Loop through each shape on the powerpoint slide and copy to the new worksheet
        For Each vPowerpointShape In vSlide.Shapes
            vPowerpointShape.Copy

            ' Create the shape on the worksheet and position it on the sheet at the same top/left as it is on the slide
            vSheet.PasteSpecial
            Set vExcelShape = vSheet.Shapes(vSheet.Shapes.Count)
            vExcelShape.Top = vPowerpointShape.Top
            vExcelShape.Left = vPowerpointShape.Left
        Next
    Next
    vPresentation.Close
    vPowerPoint.Quit

End Sub
```